# Mule CE MySQL thread connected but not running broken pipe

Tags: mysql, database, database-connection, mule, threadpool

i've this mysql configurazion whit mysql-connector-java 5.1.36. When Mule 3.7.0 CE start it prepare 10 connection. When a flow start the number of connections increase. When the flow finish the number of connections is the max number, for example 30, but only some of them are thread running, the others one are only connected. DB timeout is 86400 seconds. Sometime i've a broken pipe error. In my opinion this error is that mysql server close connections. I monitor connection by MySQL's dashboard. How i can tell Mule lo relese idle connections or reconnection strategy?

```html
<db:mysql-config name="MySQL_connection" doc:name="MySQL connection db Configuration" url="${mysql.connection.url}" >
   <db:pooling-profile maxPoolSize="100" minPoolSize="0" acquireIncrement="10" />
 </db:mysql-config>
```

Answer (score 0):

I resolved changing configuration:

```
<db:mysql-config name="MySQL_connection" doc:name="MySQL connection db Configuration" url="${mysql.connection.url}" >   </db:mysql-config>
```